# Communicate a button click event with sockets

Tags: linux, networking, ubuntu-server, sockets

**Desire:**
I have a device or micro-controller i'll call it a mc that I need to communicate to when a web page button is clicked using sockets.

```
MC1
<button id ='on1' name='mc1'>On</button>
<button id ='off1' name='mc1'>off</button>
```

**Details:**
What I am trying to accomplish is when a button is clicked pass the info to the mc.

**What I Tried:**
Currently I can listens to a port and can write data to the mc as well as receive data. 
To do this im starting a file though the server php cli. The file contains these basic socket functions.

```
 $socket = @socket_create_listen("port#");
 $client = socket_accept($socket);
 socket_write($client, $msg);
 socket_read ($client, 256);
```

the mc then connect to the server at the port#

**Problems:**
Im having difficulties understanding how to bridge the gap between my php web page with the  button and passing the data that the button has been clicked to the mc.

**Attempt at a Solution:**
Can i have the file that listens to the port run and then in a seperate file write to the client?

**additional notes**: The MC LAN I would like to avoid setting up port forwarding and the external ip sometimes changes. For these reason I had choose to have the MC establish the connection to the server thus allowing the server to write to the MC without needing port forwarding and a non changing ip address.

Thanks
JT

Comment: Don't you think that websockets could be an easiest way of solving your problem?

Comment: @Eddy_Em Dont web sockets require a browser?

Comment: No, they are based on regular sockets but allow you to use them in browsers.

Comment: @Eddy_Em can web sockets be used without a browser is my question. I was under the assumption web sockets required a browser that could interpret client side scripting such as javascript.

Comment: Websockets allow you to use both browser and console application. In case of regular sockets you can't use browser and need to write some intermediate CGI,

Comment: Please don't use tags where it says DO NOT USE such as server and communication! thanks.